# How can I turn off that LFD/CSF are sending emails with root?

Tags: linux

I'm running **CSF Firewall** on a **CentOS7** server with **Directadmin and Exim/Dovecot**.

Suddenly I receive many of the same resource emails from root@domain.tld to root@domain.tld

**I tried to turn this off by turning off many CSF Configurations like:**

- LF_ALERT_TO, LF_EMAIL_ALERT, and just many more, can share my CSF Configuration if needed.

**Also, try to avoid root emails can mail with:**

- echo "you@yourmail.com" > /root/.forward
- echo "root: you@yourmail.com" >> /etc/aliases && newaliases
- add root@domain.tld to /etc/deny senders

But still, I keep receiving many emails like this Subject:

```
LFD on core.e-volve.nl: Excessive resource usage: Redis (1725 (Parent PID:1725))
From:  <root@domain.tld>  To: root@domain.tld
```

I hope someone knows what CSF Configuration keeps sending those emails, or how I can disable root from sending emails.